# Adding a column to a mysql database using Symfony

Tags: php, sql, symfony

When I was using Symfony in my local machine if I needed to update my database schema (lets say, add a new column to a table) I modified the entity file and then I run `php console doctrine:schema:update --force`. Now my code is on a remote server (no SHH access available). I can just modify the entity again and then using phpMyAdmin to modify the table and in that way I will not need to execute the update command, but Im not sure if this is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As said in the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#creating-the-database-tables-schema), using `doctrine:schema:update --force` is powerfull, but not the best way:

> An even better way to take advantage of this functionality is via [migrations](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html), which allow you to generate these SQL statements and store them in migration classes that can be run systematically on your production server in order to track and migrate your database schema safely and reliably.

Take a look at the link in the quote (to `DoctrineMigrationsBundle`) how this works.